# pattern not match in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

Suppose to have a input type number and the numbre that can be in this type number are:

```
10.0
100.00
100
1
```

(the number can have the integer part with no limits and the decimal part with at least 2 digits). So if I put this value in the input type number `7..` the field it show my "error patter".

Thisis my html:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="home" name="home" required min="0" step="1" pattern="^[0-9]+(?:[,.]0{1,2})?$" >
```

In I use TD form and in my ts I check what kind of error is:

`form.controls.home.errors.pattern` or

```
form.controls.home.errors.pattern
```

The problem is when I put this input "`7....`". it shows me a "required" error and not a "pattern" error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `required` is a valid error here, because the `input[type="number"]` returns a value with a type of `number` and, as long as your input is not a valid number, it returns `null`.

That means, if you have a `required` validation here, it will be triggered (and this is valid again, because there is no valid number in the input).

Also, using `pattern` against `number` is a bit weird.

What you can do instead is

- a custom validator that implements any logic you want. In order to implement those (or even find ready ones) check e.g. [this repo](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation#readme)
- use standard `input[type="text"]` that does not have this drawback and can be checked with a pattern.

Comment: but the problem is in general or I must implemented Reactive Forms instead of Template form?

Comment: template form is a syntactic sugar on top of reactive forms. You can switch, of course, but it won't help that much I believe. This is connected to the nature of `input[type="number"]`, this is not really an angular issue

Answer (score 0):

> ## Issue

Your implementation looks fine however is has small issue related to your input type `number`. You are trying to assign `7..` which is basically a string value and you are trying to assign the `number` `input`. Which is not possible. Neither Angular nor HTML5 will allow you to do so.

### Fix

Fix is very simple. Just convert the `input` type control but `text` type control.

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="home" 
name="home" required min="0" step="1" pattern="^[0-9]+(?:[,.]0{1,2})?$" >
```

If you want to validate the min and max then you have those validation in Angular.

If you go further then either you need to write the `pipe` or `directive` to handle the case.

Comment: The problem is that If I have a input type number I can't put into value like "7.." or "7.,".  And this is not a correct behaviour!

Comment: Right, you can put valid numbers only.

Comment: So if the use put these value, I must show an error like "ERROR FORMAT FIELD" but when I check the error in controls, it is "required" error and not "pattern" error

Comment: Since the input field value is not assigned and form control or ngModel is not yet aware of changes.